# How to get URL from local files in the url parameter of function loadXMLDoc(url)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

In the function `loadXMLDoc(url)` there is url parameter ..and there is one file named as `abc.xml` which is saved in my local C drive. Now i want to pass these `abc.xml` in the url parameter of the function `loadXMLDoc(url)`.

Can you please suggest how to do? As i dont have any server to store the same.

Answer (score 0):

It may bot be possible because of [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) restrictions.

If your page is loaded from local file system and the xml file resides in the same directory as the html file, then you might have some luck

Comment: is any other way to load the xml document from our local drive??